# R - Extract & count all unique 2- and 3-place subsets of strings

Tags: r

I have column in a dataframe which contains sequences (of uneven length from one row to the next) composed of `0, 1, 2`. (The strings don't necessarily need to be numeric; they represent degrees of stress in syllables over whole sentences.) Minimal (very simplified) example:

```
> df
a     b
foo   0100101
bar   01201
```

What I need is a dataframe which provides every 2- or 3-place combination within that column (numbers can occur with themselves, e.g. `00`) and the total count of each combination over the whole dataframe. (A count for each row would be nice, too, but I fear that would take some reshaping, and it's not my goal right now.) Abbreviated desired result:

```
> output
combo     count
00        1
01        5
10        2
    ...
001       1
010       2
    ...
```

And so on. I've tried numerous variations on `str_count` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**

Get all 2 or 3 element combination for strings in `df$b` and then use `table` to count their frequency

```
table(unlist(lapply(c(2, 3),
                function(i) lapply(df$b,
                                function(x) sapply(1:(nchar(x) - (i - 1)),
                                                function(j) substr(x, j, j + i - 1))))))

# 00 001  01 010 012  10 100 101  12 120  20 201 
#  1   1   5   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

**2**

Use `expand.grid` to get all combinations of 2 and 3 elements for `0`, `1`, and `2`. Then, use `gregexpr` to count all the occurrences in `df$b`

```
sapply(c(do.call(paste0, (expand.grid(0:2, 0:2))),
         do.call(paste0, (expand.grid(0:2, 0:2, 0:2)))),
       function(x){
           temp = unlist(gregexpr(pattern = x, text = df$b))
           length(temp[temp != -1])
       })
# 00  10  20  01  11  21  02  12  22 000 100 200 010 110 210 020 120 220 001 
#  1   2   1   5   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   1 
#101 201 011 111 211 021 121 221 002 102 202 012 112 212 022 122 222 
#  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(a = c("foo", "bar"), b = c("0100101", "01201")), .Names = c("a", 
"b"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```